# IE/Edge click on SVG causes error - TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'blur'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, svg, microsoft-edge

I'm using an angular component (Angular UI pagination, although I don't think it's the cause of the problem), and my template includes the following...

```
<my-button ng-click="selectPage(totalPages, $event)">
    <svg>
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="domain.com/scgSprite.svg#arrow"></use>
    </svg>
</my-button>
```

The problem is that in MS Edge and IE (but not chrome) I get the following error when clicking the button.

**TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'blur'**

It doesn't happen when I click on the button but on the edge where there is no icon. I have to actually click the SVG element on the button to get the error.

Any help would really be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I have since found out that the lines in the angular-ui library that is causing the error are these...

```
if (evt && evt.target) {
    evt.target.blur();
}
```

I don't want to edit the library because then I won't be able to update it to newer versions in the future.

Is there a possibility I could add the .blur() function to svg elements in MS browsers?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, which version of Edge are you using? Also, would you be able to provide a minimal reproduction as a working snippet here on Stack Overflow, or perhaps on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I can tell you the version numbers are Microsoft Edge 25.10586.0.0 Microsoft EdgeHTML 13.10586 . Creating a fiddle would take a while but there may already be one out there that uses Angular-UI Bootstrap pagination control with an svg on the next or previous buttons?

Comment: If it wouldn't be too much of an inconvenience, I'd appreciate a small fiddle that reproduces the issue without requiring too much code. I'm an engineer on the Edge team, and this might be something we should consider supporting for better cross-browser support.

Comment: I tried here - https://plnkr.co/edit/ykHfRC?p=preview - you can see it in chrome even though the "next" button isn't styled so the SVG is actually massive and transparent. When I tried it in Edge it crashed Edge!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fixed the problem

```
if (typeof SVGElement.prototype.blur == 'undefined') {
    SVGElement.prototype.blur = function(){};
}
```